# Configuration Compile Issue

Tags: android, android-studio

Getting Configuration Error While compiling my code. I have already changed all the compile to implementation but I am not sure why I am getting this message.  Please let me know how to fix this issue. Below is the configuration of build.gradle. I am trying to connect Firebase through my app for verification

```
 Error:
    Configuration 'compile' is obsolete and has been replaced with 'implementation' and 'api'.
    It will be removed at the end of 2018. For more information see: http://d.android.com/r/tools/update-dependency-configurations.html

    Build.Gradle:App

    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 27
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "net.simplifiedcoding.firebasephoneauth"
            minSdkVersion 15
            targetSdkVersion 27
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.1'
        implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.9.7'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.6.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    }

    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

    Build.Gradle: Project:
    // Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

    buildscript {

        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
            classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.1.1'
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            google()
            jcenter()
        }
    }
        task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

Comment: Use this `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'`

Answer (score 0):

click on file->Sync Project with Gradle Files. Then clean the project and rebuild it.

Comment: Not a problem run ur project

Answer (score -2):

```
clean project and  Rebuild project
```